# Laravel get data from database with ID from unique URL

Tags: php, database, laravel, routes

I have simple problem but is hard solve this for me.

My Addin from excel create unique URL and with datas (`param1`,`mobile_number`,`message`) send to Laravel API. Main identifier is `param1`

`Laravel route`

```
Route::get('/{param1}', 'SendSmsController@index')->name('sendSms');
```

`database`

```
id  |  param1  |  mobile_number  |  message     |
----------------------------------------------------------
1   |  abc     |  123456789      |   Hi there   |
```

My goal is when i open the URL `https://my.web.com/abc` i got text message with `message` to my mobile which is stored in database.

But problem is how to identify in `controller` my  `$mobile_number` for `param1` in URL.

When i open URL with `dd($param1)` get `abc`.

Is there some way how get other columns from database ?

`laravel controller`

```
public function index($param1)
{
    return view('login')->with('param1'=>$param1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add any prefix before `param1` in your route because any route will match this param refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63272820/route-is-redirecting-to-wrong-page/63273112#63273112) for more details, we will consider this route

```
Route::get('send/sms/{param1}', 'SendSmsController@index')->name('sendSms');
```

Second to fetch the record from the route parameter there are two ways

1. You can do this

```
public function index($param1)
{
   $sms = Sms::where('param1', $param1)->first();
   
   // now you can access mobile_number,message from $sms
}
```

2. If your `param1` is unique you can add in your `Sms` model

```
/**
* Get the route key for the model.
*
* @return string
*/
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'param1';
}
```

Now in your controller you can do

```
public function index(Sms $param1)
{
   // now you can access mobile_number,message from $param1 instance
}
```

Comment: ok second way works, ````$sms = Sms::where('param1', $param1)->first();```` ````dd($sms)```` return array with all datas from database. How i can assagn them to varialbles ? ````$mobile_number = ?```` thanks

Comment: You can do `extract($sms->toArray());` now you will have 4 variables representing each key, `$id`, `$param1`, `$mobile_number` and `$message`.

Answer (score -1):

first change route method to Post then send your mobile_number or id to the route

```
// inside web.php
Route::post('/{param1}', 'SendSmsController@index')->name('sendSms');
```

in your controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     // if you send id
     $mobile_number = Model::find($request->id)->mobile_number;
     // if you send mobile_number
     $mobile_number = Model::where('mobile_number', $request->mobile_number)->first();

     // the logic to send SMS to $mobile_number
}
```

Comment: `/{param1}` is not good because every other route would get matched with this.

Comment: @Zack when i change ````route```` to post cant display ````URL```` is there any other way how to do that ?

Comment: i don't get it when you say "can't display URL". can you explain it please

Comment: @Zack change ````get```` to ````post```` return this error : ````405 Method Not Allowed````